# Dynamically adding components to JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'm trying to dynamically add some components to a JPanel, but unfortunatelly they don't appear. I only see the ones added in the constuctor.

Updated version (adding a new JPanel, where all the components will be):

```
public class View extends JPanel {

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JLabel label;
JLabel labels[];
JButton b1 = new JButton("OK");

public View() {
   this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
   this.add(panel); // adding a new JPanel
   label = new JLabel("My label");
   panel.add(label);  // adding label to the new panel (this one works)
}


public void showLabels() {
  System.out.println("function showLabels called");

  labels = new JLabel[5];

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      labels[i] = new JLabel("Label: " + i);
      panel.add(labels[i]); // this one doesn't work
  }
  panel.add(b1); // this one doesn't work, too
    this.validate(); // validating this class (parent container)
    panel.validate(); // validating the panel, where all the components are
  }
}
```

Unfortunatelly nothing changed.

Comment: Did you try calling `pack()` on the parent `JFrame`?

Comment: Not yet. Isn't it enough, to just call revalidate() or something else?

Comment: What is the layout of the JPanel? Some components can be overlapped in some layouts like BorderLayou. Try BoxLayout or FlowLayout.

Comment: I use the FlowLayout by default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call [`validate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#validate%28%29) on the parent container, as shown in the [Nested Layout Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556).  Those labels on the lower left are added dynamically.  Note that calling `pack()` might cause the size of the GUI to change, whereas calling `validate()` won't.  If you **need** to get the GUI to resize - call `pack()`, else call `validate()`.

[image]

Comment: Even when I put all my components at first on a seperat JPanel and then put the new JPanel on the first (parent) JPanel `View` and revalidate and repaint both, nothing changes...

Comment: *"revalidate and repaint"*  ..Note that I mentioned ***neither*** of those methods (for good reason).  Perhaps you are thinking of mre's answer (which has now been deleted).

Comment: Ok, I've updated my code so far. Now I'm using `validate()` only, but nothing changed.

Comment: *"my code so far"* (sigh) Please understand several things. 1) The term 'SSCCE' above is a link.  2) When I post a link, I expect you to follow it, read it, and ask if you have any questions. 3) Posting that link is (amongst other things) a hint that I won't bother looking at vague descriptions of code, or code snippets. 4) The update does **not** contain an SSCCE. -- Back to you.

Comment: *"My code is short,"* Yes.  Good so far. "..self contained,"* Direct quote **the code .. can be 'copied, pasted, compiled, run'**  The first two are fine.  The code will not **compile** until imports are added (to make it shorter, I often compromise and do 'package' imports rather than individual class imports).  The code will not **run** because it has no `main()` that creates the GUI, adds it to a top-level container and sets the container visible.  *"but I think, I'm following the rules"*  An SSCCE is a recommendation, not a rule.  Thereafter something is either 'an SSCCE' or 'not an SSCCE'